# pyspark sql module not recognizing column

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
| Cid|               Cname| acctype|  accnum|country|currency |rank   |
+----+--------------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+-------+
|6489|   u'Kristi Bradley'| current|62814653|     US|      USD|    296|
|4204| u'Elizabeth Ande...| current|18476174|     US|      USD|    237|
|6020|    u'Melody Miller'| current|84315491|     US|      USD|    285|
|9512|     u'William Wise'| deposit|37582740|     US|      USD|    277|
|7223|  u'Jackie Arellano'| current|46939546|     US|      USD|    498|
|8514|  u'Michael Hawkins'| current|90554826|     US|      USD|    498|
|6075|     u'James Garcia'| current|77363343|     US|      USD|     53|
|7700| u'Margaret Phill...| deposit|18799392|     US|      USD|    399|
```

I have pyspark sql module query like this:

```
result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT sum(rank) FROM US_df WHERE acctype ='current' ")
```

But I am getting result as null like this:

```
| _c0|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That should work. Does `SELECT rank FROM US_df WHERE acctype ='current'` return expected values?

Comment: No @BorisShchegolev the above query also did not work. However I got the expected result with the Group By clause. Thanks!